# How to run 3 task of get data (10ms) , plot chart(10ms) and save data(10ms) Synchronize?

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I have 2 timer to get data by rs485, and disaply to listView by 10ms, that I know the timer not accurate.

```
private void tmr1_Tick()
{
    ReadMessages();
}
private void tmr2_Tick()
{
    DisplayMessages();
}
```

And I used `[DllImport("winmm.dll")]` to create accurate 10ms to save data.
the class of Accurate Time is

```
    internal sealed class TimePeriod : IDisposable
    {
        private delegate void TimerEventDel(int id, int msg, IntPtr user, int dw1, int dw2);
        private const int TIME_PERIODIC = 1;
        private const int EVENT_TYPE = TIME_PERIODIC;// + 0x100;  // TIME_KILL_SYNCHRONOUS causes a hang ?!
        [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
        private static extern int timeBeginPeriod(int msec);
        [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
        private static extern int timeEndPeriod(int msec);
        [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
        private static extern int timeSetEvent(int delay, int resolution, TimerEventDel handler, IntPtr user, int eventType);
        [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
        private static extern int timeKillEvent(int id);    


    public void AccurateTimer(Form form, Action action, int delay)
    {
        mAction = action;
        mForm = form;
        timeBeginPeriod(1);
        mHandler = new TimerEventDel(TimerCallback);
        mTimerId = timeSetEvent(delay, 0, mHandler, IntPtr.Zero, EVENT_TYPE);
    }
}
mTimer1 = new TimePeriod();
mTimer1.AccurateTimer(this, new Action(WritetoTextFile), 10);
```

But if I used `AccurateTimer` to run `ReadMessages();` my code will crash by error message `callbackoncollecteddelegate`.

How can I get the 3 task by multi-thread and 10ms ?
Thanks!

Comment: Be careful with GUI, since it can introduce lattencies. First of all I would recommend to separate GUI from other critical processes by using a backgroundWorker, then, why don't you use the Timer object in C# and you add an event onTick every 10ms? In case you want 3 timers you can do that. I presume that you wish to read from 3 different ports, am I right?

Comment: A [mcve] would be useful here.

Comment: A [mcve] would be useful here.

Comment: Now I used 3 thread on each timer. But I found that the timer not always running by 10ms, sometime 20ms.  So how could I do to make sure that each timer is 10ms.